# Review of my edit

Tags: support, review-queues, edits

My edit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9166432

It says `j08691 reviewed this 1 hour ago: Edit`. Is it means that he did not edit the question itself, but my suggested edit, from the review page? Or that he made another edit before my edit was Approved/Rejected?

Also, why isn't his name under the `Reviewer Stats`? Is that a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is intentional; the information you seek is under the ["Revisions" link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/32016152/revisions).

What happened was:

- You suggested an edit
- This person came along, felt like your edit accomplished *most* of what it should have, then decided to add an edit of their own
- At that point in time you received credit for the edit with 2 reputation as evidenced here:  [image]
- The other person contributed their own edit to the post, thus giving them the last credit for the edit that you see.
- The screen that you're looking at only concerns itself with the single suggested edit; that sliver in time.  It wouldn't convey the additional actions made by others.

Long story short:  there is no bug, and this scenario played out exactly how it should have.

Comment: This is the "Improve Edit" behavior that reviewers can choose.  And this is how that works.